# How to use 'GetSheetByName' with a macro in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a macro to run once a month to collect current figures from a set of formulas, but I'm struggling to get it to select the right sheet before running the copy and paste commands.

```
function RecordCurrentFigures() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Current Figures');
  spreadsheet.getRange('9:9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5:F5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5:F5').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please elaborate "but I'm struggling to get it to select the right sheet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are calling it but you're not using it afterwards, you are using `getActiveSheet` and `getActiveRange` instead.

Try:

```
function RecordCurrentFigures() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Current Figures');
  var range = sheet.getRange('9:9')
  sheet.insertRowsBefore(range.getRow(), 1);
  // range.offset(0, 0, 1, range.getNumColumns()); // this is a NOP
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('B9');
  sheet.getRange('B5:F5').copyTo(range2, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
  sheet.getRange('B5:F5').copyTo(range2, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: So it Pasted it in the right place but copied it for the first sheet.

Comment: Ok, then try adjusting ```getSheetByName``` to the correct sheet if it's not 'Current Figures'

Comment: So 'Current Figures' is where I want to copy from and paste to.  I want to copy from B5:F5, Insert a new row above 9:9 then Paste the format then paste values into B9.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful Jesse!